# Matching on digit characters in a text node and changing them to an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Having trouble with this XSL transform in my XHTML.

Illustration of my source doc:

```
<blockquote>
    <center>
       <h1>CHAPTER 100. RANDOM TEXT HERE </h1>
    </center>
    <center>
       <h1>CHAPTER 200. RANDOM TEXT HERE </h1>
    </center>
</blockquote>
```

My desired output:

```
<title chapter="100"> CHAPTER 100. RULES OF SOMETHING TEXT HERE </title>
<title chapter="200"> CHAPTER 200. RULES OF SOMETHING TEXT HERE </title>
```

Any ideas on how I could add this to my XSLT stylesheet? Would I use regex here to help me match on the chapter #?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?  How to make a given template match on H1 elements with content of the form "CHAPTER nnn. text ..."? Or how to parse the string "CHAPTER nnn.  text text text ..." into its parts?

Comment: I want to grab the chapter number in each h1 and make that into an attribute as shown in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it would involve something like

```
<xsl:template match="h1">
  <title chapter="{replace(., 'CHAPTER\s+(\d+)', '$1')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </title>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given input of the form shown, in XSLT 1.0 you can do something like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:template match="h1">
  <title chapter="{
      substring-before(
        substring-after(.,'CHAPTER '),
        '. '
      )}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </title>
</xsl:template>
```

This may produce sub-optimal results on irregular input.

In XSLT 2.0, you have (as Michael Kay has just observed) a richer set of regular-expression functions that will allow you to deal more conveniently with some irregularities in your input; the `matches()`, `tokenize()` and `replace()` functions are worth reading up on.

Comment: Definitely I will look more into those, am just starting out here in XSL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the source is HTML, you want to convert that to pure XML.

I would go for loading the entire source document into a DOM tree, and create the target XML from there. Nearly all languages have a way to read a source from string or file into a DOM tree. A SAX parser can also be used for this purpose, just write the code for the parser to convert the input into the desired output.

It can also be done using regex I guess, but there is no way of checking the validity of the output, using a real tree/parser has all these functions (weather DOM/SAX etc).

Comment: Might even parse better because it is more strict then normal HTML. But what do you want to do, just convert the source to the target from the command line, or you have some application?

Comment: but without any functional programming language? (like java/C++/php/perl etc)

Comment: The source document comes from just raw page source I have run through HTML tidy. It's an executable I run from the command line through a script on a bunch of raw .html files. But that is how I get this valid XHTML.

Comment: I see, checking some info on that XSL at this moment. I also see it has some programming elements like: <xsl:for-each select="<something"> I guess you can use those to convert to your preferred format.

Comment: Here ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472837/xpath-xslt-selecting-a-node-where-the-parent-nodes-attribute-matches-the-att?rq=1)) I also see some these programming elements for converting, I guess you should take a good look at these examples and apply them to your situation.